# Phong ShaderMaterial parameters / setting Defines

Tags: three.js

I'm currently customizing the base phong material using `THREE.ShaderMaterial` and rebuilding the material with most of THREE js's base chunks and a customized fragment shader chunk. The problem I'm having is with the `#define's` in many part of three.js and trying to find the proper way to set them.

In the actual program it goes like this

```
// Clone the uniforms
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader['uniforms']);

// Set uniform values
uniforms["map"].value = texture;
uniforms["diffuse"].value = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );
uniforms["envMap"].value = envMapt;
uniforms["reflectivity"].value = 0.7;

// Create material using shader
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  vertexShader: shader['vertexShader'],
  fragmentShader: shader['fragmentShader'],
  uniforms: uniforms,
  lights: true,
  //map: true, // These don't  seem to do anything
  //envMap: true // These don't  seem to do anything
} );
```

With a custom shader built like this

```
    fragmentShader: [

        "#define USE_MAP",
        //"#define USE_ENVMAP",
        "uniform vec3 diffuse;",
        "uniform float opacity;",

.......
        "void main() {",

            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "alphatest_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "specularmap_fragment" ],
......

            // NDJ - Using custom frag shader
            //THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lights_phong_fragment" ],
            CustomShaderChunk[ "lights_phong_fragment" ],
......

            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_fragment" ],

        "}"

    ].join("\n")
```

By manually adding the required #defines at the start of the shaders I can get it to do what I want. However this doesn't seem like the proper way to set it and it isn't very flexible.

Something similar to [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2412), But I only need the base definitions. I've tried looking through the api and examples to find how to set these but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it exactly as you described. Here is a sample:

```
ph = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x000000,
                    color: 0x0020ff,
                    specular: 0x2040ff,
                    shininess: 30,
                    map: theMap,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
ph.defines = {waldo_waldo_three: '(dx+3)', wonke: 7};
```

if you're being prudent, be careful about overwriting any exsiting 'defines' object